# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes minutes after login

Tags: freeze

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04 in the past without any issues on my desktop (dual boot with Windows 10 on separate SSD's). At point I tried upgrading to 18.04 and then my computer would freeze just a couple of minutes after login, which made me revert back to Ubuntu 16.04. Recently I decided to try a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04, but I am having the same issue. Usually 2-3 minutes after logging in, my PC just freezes and mouse and keyboard are not working. I bought a new SSD (WD 500GB) and tried to clean install on the new drive, but I am having the same issue. I read a lot of topics that it may be Nvidia related, so I tried multiple Nvidia drivers ( 340,390,440, and the open source nouveau one) but the problem persists. Since mouse and keyboard are not working, I cannot press ctrl+alt+f2 to try to debug the issue or at least find the source of the problem.

I have been a casual user of Ubuntu in the past and used it mainly for development purposes so I am not very familiar with how I can find the source of the problem. I need to sort out the issue because I need to set up Ubuntu on my desktop for work purposes and I am desperate. Any hints on what command outputs I need to post here to help reach a solution would be greatly appreciated!

Specifications:
Motherboard: MSI 970a-g43

Processor: AMD FX-6300

Graphics Card: NVIDIA GTX 750 Ti

Memory: G.Skill PC 1333 8GB 1333 MHz DDR3

Edit:

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
V10.6

free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7,7Gi       841Mi       5,9Gi       2,0Mi       995Mi       6,6Gi
Swap:         2,0Gi          0B       2,0Gi

 ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
ls: cannot access '/home/stavros/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory

ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jul 31 19:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jul 31 19:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 31 19:29 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul 31 19:29 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul 31 19:29 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Update: The issue has been fixed by installing the 5.9 Ubuntu kernel!

Comment: Does this happen with a newly created user? Does this happen also with Ubuntu 20.04 live cd?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `free -h` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`... more in next comment...,

Comment: Ryzen processors are notorious for memory compatibility issues. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: This can also be a problem with some hardware. I have a similar issue with a logitech mouse driver. After I started using another mouse the freezes went away.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you for your help! I edited my post to include the info that you asked for. I also run the memtest test twice ( 2 full passes) and no errors were found.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli  Yes it does it with a newly created user and it also happened when i tried to reinstall ubuntu from a live cd once.

Comment: Please see my answer. I'm not sure that updating to the 5.9 kernel is the correct fix. Also, memtest should be run for 4/4 tests to verify RAM. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema memtest reportes no issues after 4/4 tests. since i upgraded my kernels the issue did not reoccur.

Comment: @zakos The MSI web site is down, so the BIOS information that I have is probably incorrect. I've updated my answer...

Comment: @zakos The MSI web site is back up. If your BIOS and motherboard info is correct, you may possibly have the wrong BIOS installed. Please review.

Comment: @heynnema I have bios version A.6 installed, which is the latest bios driver for my motherboard.

Comment: @zakos In your question you indicate "V10.6". Typo?

Comment: @heynnema apparently this is the name that shows up when you install A.6. I have double checked and have the latest bios available.

Answer (score 2):

The issue has been solved by updating the linux kernel to 5.9. Thanks to everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to kernel 5.8 on Ubuntu 20.04.

The same thing happened with me and it resolved after the upgrade.

Visit [Upgrading Ubuntu to Linux kernel 5.8: A case for and against it](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/a-case-for-and-against-upgrading-ubuntu-to-kernel-5-8-and-how-to-do-it/) for details.

Comment: Thank you! This has fixed the freezing issue, no freezes have happened after the upgrade. The only issue that I have now is that the peripherals that are plugged in USB 3.0 ports are not responding/are not recognized. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Update: The 3.0 USB issue appears to be kernel-specific and has been fixed by installing the 5.9 kernel. Big thanks to everyone for helping me out, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

For other Ubuntu users, this might help.

If you used `nouveau.modeset=0` in `/etc/default/grub`, remove it.
In my case, this is the culprit. Concretely, this is what I have done.

Before:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nouveau.modeset=0"
```

After:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="" #nouveau.modeset=0"
```

After that do `sudo update-grub` and reboot (`sudo init 6`). Do it fast before it freezes.
For sure the nouveau is what reason for the freeze.